# Position UserControl in Grid Programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm loading UserControls from external dll's.
My MainWindow contains a Grid and everything is placed within the grid.

How to a position the UserControl in the Grid from codebehind?

Here is how i'm adding the control currently.

```
UserControl ucSupportButton = 
    new Bootstrapper().LoadUserControl("SC.Support.dll", "Button");
MainGrid.Children.Add(ucSupportButton );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to specify value for `Grid.Column` and/or `Grid.Row` attached properties you can use `Grid` static methods:

```
Grid.SetRow(ucSupportButton, 1);
Grid.SetColumn(ucSupportButton , 1);
```

Comment: I would just add that you can do that because Grid.Row and Grid.Column are attached properties